# Are routes cached by Host or by URL Map in Google Cloud CDN for HTTP(S) Load Balancing?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Google Cloud CDN for HTTP(S) Load Balancing was recently announced (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cdn).

Consider the following setup:

1. I have an HTTP Load Balancer with a single URL Map that accepts all hosts and routes them to the same backend service
2. I serve two separate websites, a.com and b.com from the backend service
3. a.com and b.com both serve a unique cacheable asset at the same path, e.g. /favicon.ico (imagine it is a letter A icon on a.com and a letter B icon on b.com)

Will Google Cloud CDN cache requests to a.com/favicon.ico and b.com/favicon.ico separately due to the assets being on different hosts?  Or since they both fall under the same URL Map at the same path, will they be viewed as the same request by Google Cloud CDN?

The documentation makes it unclear because cache invalidation references take a URL Map and a path as an argument.  There is no option to provide a host in cache invalidation, which makes it seam as if the host is not considered when caching an asset:

```
gcloud alpha compute url-maps invalidate-cache URL_MAP --path PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google Cloud CDN considers the whole URL when caching, so http://a.example.com/favicon.ico and http://b.example.com/favicon.ico will be treated as separate resources.

Comment: Are there plans to add a --host parameter to the invalidate-cache call then?  It seems that it would make more sense to call the invalidate-cache call on the LoadBalancer itself with a --host and --path parameter instead of calling it on the URL Map.

Comment: When you say the load balancer itself, what type of Google Compute Engine resource are you referring to? The cloud.google.com UI refers to URL map resources as "HTTP load balancers", and the gcloud CLI requires you specify an URL map when initiating a cache invalidation.

I agree that adding a --host argument would make sense.

Comment: Good point, URL Map is the right resource.  I was getting URL Maps confused with Path Matchers.  A --host argument would help out a lot for those of us running multiple sites (I run >20 through the same URL Map).  Should I open an issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list